# Где сохраняют данные плагины WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Всё изменяемое через панель управления хранится в базе данных.

Где хранят данные плагины?

Например, плагин *TablePress*, позволяющий добавлять таблицы на сайт.
Для корректной работы достаточно загрузить через админку файл определённого формата и вывести где угодно путём шорткода.

Я загрузил несколько файлов через этот плагин, и попытался найти их в phpMyAdmin - безуспешно.
Порылся в файлах плагина - вновь безуспешно.

Где всё содержится?

Comment: 1) В PhpMyAdmin ничего не хранится, PhpMyAdmin -- это интерфейс для работы с БД, не более. Хранится все в базе данных. 2) Плагины могут создавать свои таблицы и хранить в них данные в базе данных, также могут хранить данные в файловой системе. Плохо искали.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за информацию. Подскажите, а я имею полный доступ ведь к БД через phpMyAdmin? Даже к тому, что создают плагины в этой БД?

Comment: @IgorR. технически ты прав, но ТАК изменять вопрос - плохая практика.

Comment: @SeVlad "Я загрузил несколько файлов через этот плагин, и попытался найти их в phpMyAdmin - безуспешно.  
Порылся в файлах плагина - вновь безуспешно. " -- как улучшает вопрос эта вода?

Comment: @КириллДостоевский да, все Вам доступно. Но, изменять в БД данные нужно острожно, а лучше напрямую самому в БД вообще не менять.

Comment: @IgorR. Понял, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из вопроса непонятно, что именно вы пытаетесь найти.

Таблицы плагина, которые доступны в админке по адресу `/wp-admin/admin.php?page=tablepress`, хранятся в таблице `wp_posts` как посты кастомного типа `tablepress_table`.

Файлы импорта ("загрузить через админку файл определённого формата") не хранятся нигде. Они преобразуются в посты кастомного типа и хранятся в базе, как указано выше.

Comment: Файлы импорта я и пытался найти, но теперь понимаю что к чему. Спасибо.